# frequency response using FFTW and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, fftw

I'm working with fftw and openCV and I'm able to produce the fft and iffft results. Can someone please tell me how visualize the frequency response after fft?

Also, I'd like to know whether its possible to separate magnitude and phase data in order to process them separately?

Comment: You mean to visualize the sine+cos functions generated by Fourier-Transform ?

Comment: visualizing the phase...

Comment: Like a histogram? Phase&freq. versus  magnitude?

Comment: like this: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/cln1fur2.gif

Comment: Thats 2D magnitude of phases?